# How to keep track of order in which switch case values are executed?

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement

How can I keep track of the order in which `switch` case statements are executed?

For example:

```
while (some_boundary) {    
    switch (value) {
        case a:
            do something;
            move to next value;
            break;
        case b:
            do something;
            move to next value;
            break;
        case c:
            do something;
            move to next value;
            break;
    } 
}
```

I want to know if the `switch` was executed `abc` or `bac` or `cab`, etc.

Any idea ? Or will implementing via `if/else` make more sense ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean here. *value* will only match one switch item.

Comment: Maybe you are asking about how switch is implemented internally?

Comment: He means to keep track. switch is in a while loop, so he wants to know the sequence of switch choices along the while iterations.

Comment: Please, if any of the answers solved your problem, mark it as accepted answer. Otherwise, tell us so we can help you further.

Answer (score 1):

You can save a vector at every iteration with the value of the corresponding iteration:

```
std::vector<int> sequence;
while (some_boundary) {
    int temp = computeValue(); // Or however you get your value.
    sequence.push_back(temp);
    switch (temp) {
    case a:
        //do something;
        break;
    case b:
         //do something;
        break;
    case c:
        //do something;
    break;
    } 
}
```

Edit: This is assuming that value is set somewhere between the while and the switch, so you can save it in advance. Other option is to include the push_back instruction in every case, but is more "dirty". Preallocating the vector could save some computation time as well.

Edit2: code modified according the suggestions so that it is ensured that a new value will be computed.

Comment: You can always "save it in advance", even if you are `switch`'ing on a calculated value.  Simply assign the result of the calculation to a temp variable, save the variable in the vector, and then `switch` on the variable.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not get your point. Isn't that whaat I am saying?

Comment: A `switch` has to have a concrete value to evaluate, whether that be `switch(variable)` or `switch(expression)`. In the first case, you would do `push_back(variable); switch(variable)`. In the second case, you would do `int temp = expression; push_back(temp); switch(temp)` instead. So you can always guarantee that a "value is set somewhere between the while and the switch, so you can save it in advance", there is no assumption needed. I am not criticizing the code in your answer, I am criticizing the wording of your "Edit".

Comment: I don't think the edit is necessary because the original version has "move to next value". Perhaps it would help to make "get initial value" explicit. Alternatively, keep the edit and remove "move to next value" entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know (and not save the results) you could just output the value at each iteration.  Try

```
cout << value << endl;
```

as the first line within the while loop.